# Minimize integral

Tags: definite-integrals, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Find numbers A and B such that the integral is minimal

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\vert%
\,\vphantom{\Large A}{\rm e}^{-x} - A{\rm e}^{-2x} - B{\rm e}^{-3x}\,
\right\vert^{2}\,{\rm d}x
$$

I have tried to find an orthonormal basis so I can compute the projection between the functions without success. All help is very appreciated, and what is the best way of finding an orthonormal basis of similar problems ?.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the notation, are the vertical lines just absolute values or norms of some kind? If they symbolise abs value they are unnecessary, no?

And we can just find $\partial_A I$ and $\partial _B I$ and set them both to zero? Doing so gives us the system of equations in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal I} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\verts{\sum_{n = 1}^{3}a_{n}\expo{-nx}}^{2}
\,\dd x\,,\quad a_{1} = 1,\quad a_{2} = -A\,,\quad a_{3} = -B}$.
$$
{\cal I}=
\sum_{m = 1}^{3}\sum_{n = 1}^{3}a_{m}^{*}a_{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\pars{m + n}x}\,\dd x
=
\sum_{m = 1}^{3}\sum_{n = 1}^{3}{a_{m}^{*}a_{n} \over m + n}
$$
With $m = 2, 3$:
$$
0 = \partiald{{\cal I}}{{a_{m}^{*}}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{3}{a_{n} \over m + n}
={1 \over m + 1} + \sum_{n = 2}^{3}{a_{n} \over m + n}\quad\imp\quad
\sum_{n = 2}^{3}{a_{n} \over m + n} = -\,{1 \over m  + 1} 
$$
$$
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
-\,{1 \over 4}\,A & - & {1 \over 5}\,B & = & -\,{1 \over 3}
\\
-\,{1 \over 5}\,A & - & {1 \over 6}\,B & = & -\,{1 \over 4}
\end{array}\right.
\quad\imp\quad
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
15A & + & 12B & = & 20
\\
12A & + & 10B & = & 15
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
A = {10 \over 3}\,,\qquad B = -\,{5 \over 2}} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing an ONB it is easier to work  from basic principles: the vector connecting $e^{-x}$ to the nearest point in the plane is orthogonal to the plane. Thus, $e^{-x}-Ae^{-2x} -Be^{-3x}$ must be orthogonal to both $e^{-2x}$  and $e^{-3x}$. This requirement amounts to $$\frac13 - \frac{A}{4}-\frac{B}{5}=0\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{1}{4}-\frac{A}{5}-\frac{B}{6}=0$$ 
Hence $A=10/3$ and $B=-5/2$.

<sup>My original answer was wrong, I corrected it after seeing Felix Martin's answer, thinking there is still  some merit to this approach.</sup>